# Angular2 sibling communication via Observable -Best practice?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I have a [*simple app*](https://plnkr.co/edit/iIy1kZWP8nRuhmLwGFh2?p=info) which involves sibling components communication.
this is done via Observable.

This is done by a service :

```
@Injectable()
export class SharedService {

  private caseNumber = new Subject<string>();  

  caseNumber$ = this.caseNumber.asObservable(); //components subscribe to this <--

  publishData(data: string) {
    this.caseNumber.next(data);
  }
```

But  I can also do it [*in a different way*](https://plnkr.co/edit/g4tJEEqGrxCZcGdZJ99e?p=preview) :

```
@Injectable()
export class SharedService {

  caseNumber$ = new Subject<string>();  //components subscribe to this <--

  publishData(data: string) {
    this.caseNumber$.next(data);
  }
```

**Question**

What are the differences between those two approaches and which one should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subjects are Read-Write Observables, they are used when you are creating Observable imperatively (not from event, callback, etc), all the logic of the broadcasting is internal to your class / service.

Usually it is a better practice to expose observables instead of subjects, except if you need your external component to modify it.

**But**, note that would be weird to modify it through the Subject instead of some public method, as it is the service which is responsible of maintaining the `Subject`, it might lead to unexpected side-effect as the broadcasting is made imperatively.

Consider this service :

```
class FooService{
  foo = new Subject<Foo>();
  bar:boolean=false;
  setFoo(foo:Foo){
    this.bar=true;
    this.foo.next(foo);
  }
  doStuff(){
    if(this.bar){
      //do stuff
    }
  }
}
```

if an object emitted a value through `fooService.foo.next(new Foo());`, the `bar` property (some state) would not be updated, so there might be a problem when calling `fooService.doStuff()`. That's why it might be better to expose an Observable to the outside world, and keep your Subject private. But note that, as would say people from the python world, "we are all consenting adults".

[A good article](http://davesexton.com/blog/post/To-Use-Subject-Or-Not-To-Use-Subject.aspx) on the topic "should I use a Subject or an Observable ?".

Comment: So which one is better first or second example of mine ?

Comment: I would say the first as the second allows an external object to modify the state.

Comment: Oh so it's like the Promise() interface ( which reduces the resolve method etc)

Comment: well more or less, an Observable is read-only while a subject is read-write.

Comment: What do you mean by _modify the state_ ? Both code snippets are causing `*.next()`

Comment: `this.foo="bar"` this is a state modification.

Comment: Iit's my lunch break right now,i'm writing on my mobile, i'll add an example when i get back to the office.

Comment: I added an example, I hope this help